# Does the following indicate a bad design?

Tags: c++, class, dependencies

I was wondering whether you think the following code usually indicates a bad design ...

```
class X
{
public:
  ...
private:
  Y y;
};

Class Y
{
public:
   Y( X& value ){ x = value; };
private:
   X& x;
}
```

(i.e. there is some sort of cyclic dependency between the classes X and Y).

Comment: @Amardeep: Would you care to elaborate?

Comment: `x = value` needs to be in an initialization list, or this won't compile. :-)

Comment: @Oli: Cyclic dependency is the antithesis of loose coupling.  But as I look at it more closely and realize it is just reference of X in Y, it doesn't look so awful anymore.

Comment: Your code doesn't compile. And *that* is bad design. It may be a trivial typo, but if we don't know what your code actually looks like, we have to guess at what we meant, and then we can't be sure our answers are correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, I don't think it is bad design. It looks like a parent-child relationship (which is 1-to-1) where the child has a pointer back to the parent.

The main reason for such a design is if someone could get a reference to `Y` without coming through `X`. If all access to `Y` are done only through `X`, such a reference is more questionable.

As Billy ONeal points out, one example could be an iterator that needs to be able to reference the collection it belongs to. This could make it possible to have an iterator into an array that doesn't need to be invalidated when the array is resized, as it would check the array's current buffer address and current size on each access.

Another example could be an `OrderLine` class (your `X`) which holds a reference to the item and a quantity count etc. It also has an optional member of type `DigitalLicense` (your `Y`). `DigitalLicense` contains a large encrypted description of the license, so it's only included in those `OrderLines` that corresponds to a product with a digital license.

On construction, a reference to the `DigitalLicense` is also put in a separate map, keyed on the license id. It is now possible to look up a `DigitalLicense` based on the license id in the map. Then the back reference is used to go from the `DigitalLicense` to the `OrderLine`. If the `OrderLine` has a similar back reference it is possible to get back to the `Order` as well.

Comment: Can you elaborate on some of the several good reasons? I'm not saying you're wrong but I always consider a "child" that needs a pointer to its "parent" a "code smell" but I'm always willing to learn about exceptions where it would be a good design.

Comment: @Charles: It may be useful for allowing you to traverse the tree of which they're part. I believe `std::map` works like this. Without that extra parent pointer, incrementing an iterator would not be an `O(1)` operation as required.

Comment: @jalf: Yes, I can see that for inherently tightly coupled objects it could be a good idea. Often, though, I've seen children know about the type of their parent (and the fact that they have one!) when a better design is to have the child ignorant of where (or how) it is owned and therefore inherently more flexible and reusable in more situations. With classes called `X` and `Y` it's all a bit abstract.

Comment: @Charles: Yeah, agreed there.

Answer (score 7):

Depends on what you're trying to do. Some designs, such as iterators, require these kinds of cycles.

Answer (score 2):

in former times e.g. in VB6 this was bad design, because VB couldn't delete both objects, where one was referenced in another and vice versa. since C++ does not have reference counting, it's no problem any more.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is problematic.  In fact, it's a rather common pattern (i.e. a child object maintains a pointer/reference to parent object).

Answer (score 1):

This is not necessarily bad design, indeed it's fairly common.  However, you do need to be very careful with these kind of designs when dealing with memory management.  You can end up with tricky bugs when each class depends on the other like this.